# Linux evdev subsystem vs libusb

Tags: linux, usb, usb-device, hid

What are the advantages and disadvantages to using the `evdev` subsystem versus accessing input devices using `libusb`?

The [kernel docs for evdev](https://docs.kernel.org/input/input.html#evdev) state:

> This is the preferred interface for userspace to consume user input,
> and all clients are encouraged to use it.

That's strong language. From python (for example) I can access an HID device with https://github.com/gvalkov/python-evdev or https://github.com/trezor/cython-hidapi. These seem to achieve the same goal. Does using `libusb` add latency?

[How does libusb access kernel stuff?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109406/how-does-libusb-access-kernel-stuff) does not seem to mention `evdev`. Does `libusb` use `libevdev` or a similar subsystem?

Comment: Evdev is dealing with things two layers above what libusb does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evdev abstracts input devices.

Libusb is only useful if you want to write a userland driver for your specific USB input device. Libusb just offers you raw access to USB. It has no notion of what a hid is. It knows no mice, keyboards or touchscreens. A typical example of what libusb is used for is printer drivers, which have nothing to do with input devices, or even Linux - you can compile the exact same printer driver for Linux, OpenBSD and OS X.

Unless you want to write a USB device driver in userland, libusb is not what you want.

It's really hard to compare evdev and libusb, because they serve completely different purposes; really, evdev is Linux' input device abstraction layer, which knows and understands inputs but doesn't care about USB, and libusb is just a library that knows Linux' USB userland interface and doesn't care or know about its input device subsystem.

It's not clear to me what you want, but if it is dealing with an input device, then you want evdev, if not even a library building atop of that, like libinput or even higher-level abstractions as delivered with GUI toolkits.